# Form submission shows the result after the second page refresh only in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, magento

I created a form where as soon as I click on the input of the submit, it writes me a value on the column to the database table.

So far everything is fine, but when the current page reloads, I can't see the result that was written to the database.
I can only see the result if I submit the form for the second time on the same page.

My code:

```
<?php 
$increId = $_order->getRealOrderId();
$pathAss = 'My file';   
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');


$table = 'sales_flat_order';
$query = "UPDATE ".$table." "
       . "SET upload_file_1='" . $pathAss . "'"
       . " WHERE increment_id='".$increId."'";

$connectionWrite->query($query); 
?>

<form id="abbLogoOrder" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <a href="<?php echo $_order->getupload_file_1(); ?>" 
       title="<?php echo basename($_order->getupload_file_1()); ?>">
        <?php echo basename($_order->getupload_file_1()); ?>
    </a> //THIS VALUE RETURNS EMPTY AFTER FIRST SUBMIT FORM

    <b>
    <?php 
    /* $testget = ['getupload_file_'.$count.'()'];
    echo $_order->$testget;  */
    ?>
    </b>

    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
        <button class="btn" style="font-size:13px;">SELECT YOUR FILES</button>
        <input type="file" name="abbFile<?php echo $count; ?>[]" id="abbFile<?php echo $count; ?>" multiple="multiple" />         
        <input type="submit" value="SEND" />    
    </div>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$mysqli -> affected_rows;` in mysqli  and `rowCount` in pdo : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_affected_rows.asp success message you are getting means all your sent variables are inserted.

Comment: It took me a while to edit the code so that it was even readable. A few suggestions: 1) For readability, never use tabs. It may line up for you, but it won’t for everybody else. Your editor should be able to convert tabs to spaces. 2) You’re wide open to sql injection. Use prepared statements. 3) POST submissions should be followed by a redirect with GET (PRG pattern) after you deal with user input. Sorry none of these comments help your problem, but it’s unclear how `$_order` gets its information.

Comment: Check what returns on $increId when page reloads. It might be null I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not re-fetching the order details after the save function. So the details are getting from the initial state, so the result is old, but the next reload it changes to updated value and shows the right output.

But still it's unclear where you are loading the order object.

Comment: Maybe I understand the problem. When you submit the form, you do not completely reload the page, therefore it does not update the data. I forced the refresh of the page and now I can see the results after sending the form only once.

Thank you very much for your help. :)